# Postfix Evaluation, how to tell compiler what operator to perform, because in the equation we have given Postfix expression in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

Postfix evaluation algorithm.
The task is to iterate over the expression and

1. If the current item is an operand, push its value onto the stack.
2. If the current item is an operator:(a) Pop the top two operands off the stack.
   (b) Perform the operation.(c) Push the result of this operation back onto the stack.

```
equation = "ABC+*D/"
a = 8, b = 2, c = 3, d = 42
stack = Stack()

for x in equation:
    if x.isalpha():
        stack.push(x)
    else:
        i = stack.peek()
        stack.pop()
        j = stack.peek()
        stack.pop()
```

Comment: Have you tried using some `if` statements?

Comment: the problem is the operator is given as string type so how would the compiler know what it is?

Comment: The compiler doesn't know. You have to write the code to implement this. Such as: `if op == '+': result = i + j`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using single dict for values instead of multiple variables (if you need another approach, you can use eval to do it).

```
from collections import deque
eq = 'ABC+*D/'
vars = {'A':8, 'B':2, 'C':3, 'D':10}
ops = {
    '+': lambda x,y : y + x,
    '-': lambda x,y : y - x,
    '*': lambda x,y : y * x,
    '/': lambda x,y : y / x,
}
stack = deque()

for x in eq:
    if x in ops:
        stack.append(ops[x](stack.pop(), stack.pop()))
    else:
        stack.append(vars[x])
print(stack)
```

If you need variables, then the following will work:

```
from collections import deque
eq = 'ABC+*D/'
a, b, c, d = 8, 2, 3, 10
ops = {
    '+': lambda x,y : y + x,
    '-': lambda x,y : y - x,
    '*': lambda x,y : y * x,
    '/': lambda x,y : y / x,
}
stack = deque()

for x in eq:
    if x in ops:
        stack.append(ops[x](stack.pop(), stack.pop()))
    else:
        stack.append(eval(x.lower()))
print(stack[0])
```